# Find and replace every second occurence with sed

Tags: regex, bash, replace, sed

Hi all I have the code below

> find . -type f -exec sed -i 's@EText-No.@New EText-No. @g' {} +

I have been using the script to find and replace some characters in multiple files in folders and subfolders. 
I have discovered that some values occurs more than twice. Hence I need to modify my script to replace only the second instance of an attribute

> find . -type f -exec sed -i '/Subject/{:a;N;/Subject.*Subject/!Ta;s/Subject/SecondSubject/2;}/g' {} +

I am trying to use the code above to achive this .. but it seems not to be working. I need to modify the code to work with "@" as a seperatore like the above code. because I have backlash characters in my file. 
Any Idea how I might make the code to work and using the sperator @?

Thanks for your help

ORIGINAL FILE BEFORE PROCESSING

`<tr><th scope="row">Subject</th><td>United States -- Biography</td></tr><tr><th scope="row">Subject</th><td>United States -- Short Stories</td></tr><tr><th scope="row">EText-No.</th><td>24200</td></tr><tr><th scope="row">Release Date</th><td>2008-01-07</td></tr><tr>`

After processing

`<tr><th scope="row">Subject</th><td>United States -- Biography</td></tr><tr><th scope="row">SecondSubject</th><td>United States -- Short Stories</td></tr><tr><th scope="row">EText-No.</th><td>24200</td></tr><tr><th scope="row">Release Date</th><td>2008-01-07</td></tr><tr>`

Please note that the second Subject is changed from 'Subject' to 'SecondSubject'

Comment: `find . -type f -exec sed -i 's@Subject@{:a;N;/Subject.*Subject/!Ta;s/Subject/SecondSubject/2;}@g' {} +`

Comment: Fix headline or text. Do you want to "replace every second occurence" or "replace only the second instance"?

Comment: Thanks Cyrus  I need to replace every second occurence

Comment: HI Udy.. You code did not work.. It replace Subject with '{:a;N;/Subject.*Subject/!Ta;s/Subject/SecondSubject/2;}'

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
sed -i '/Subject/{:a;s/\(Subject.*\)Subject/\1SecondSubject/;tb;N;ba;:b}'
```

If a line appended to the pattern space (with the N command) contains more than one occurrence of the word "Subject", then you can use this command to only target the first occurrence of the appended line (the second occurrence of the pattern space):

```
sed -i '/Subject/{:a;/Subject.*Subject/!{N;ba;};s/Subject/newSubject/2;}'
```

Comment: This is how the code look like after adding sub folder processing **'find . -type f -exec sed -i '/Subject/{:a;s/\(Subject.*\)Subject/\1SecondSubject/;tb;N;ba;:b}' {} +'**

Comment: Hi Casimir. There is a problem with this script.. In a situation where there is up to 3 instances of Subject. The script is replacing the third. instance. I just need the script to replace only the second instance. Any Ideas?

Comment: Thank you once again.. You are a genius